# Vue TypeScript error: A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter. ts(2556)

Tags: typescript

I have a Vue 3 TypeScript composable function for handling api endpoints.

I'm trying to use `...args` to take in an unknown number of arguments to use on various endpoints.

But it is giving me a TypeScript and Eslint error.

A trimmed down version of my function looks something like this:

```ts
const endpoints = {
  async setFirstName(firstName: string) {
    return await updateDocTask.perform('users', firebaseUser.uid, firstName);
  },
  async getFirstName() {
    const user = await getDocTask.perform('users', firebaseUser.uid);
    return user.firstName;
  },
  async setLastName(lastName: string) {
    return await updateDocTask.perform('users', firebaseUser.uid, lastName);
  },
  async getLastName() {
    const user = await getDocTask.perform('users', firebaseUser.uid);
    return user.lastName;
  },
  async setProfilePhotoURL(photoFile: File | undefined) {
    return await updateProfilePhotoTask.perform(photoFile);
  },
};

export const useUserTask = (
  operation: 'get' | 'set',
  endpointName: 'ProfilePhotoURL' | 'FirstName' | 'LastName',
) => {
  const setterName = `set${endpointName}` as const;
  const getterName = `get${endpointName}` as const;
  const endpointHandler =
    operation === 'set' ? endpoints[setterName] : endpoints[getterName];
  return useTask(function* (signal, ...args) {
    const data: string | undefined = yield endpointHandler(signal, ...args); // TypeScript and Eslint errors here
    return data;
  });
};
```

TypeScript error:

```
A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter. ts(2556)
```

Eslint error:

```
Unsafe spread of an `any` array type. eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument
```

How do I fix these errors?